# A problem about the existence of increasing coloring groups

Tags: co.combinatorics, young-tableaux, colorings

Got stuck on this one for months.

Given a sequence of non decreasing positive integers $a_1, .., a_n$, let there be $a_i$ balls labeled the number i, for each $1 \leq i \leq n$. Suppose there is a k coloring of the balls where different color has different number of distinct labels. Let’s call this a special k coloring on $a_1, .., a_n$.

Now suppose we add $a_{n+1}$ more balls labeled $n+1$, where $\sum_{i=1}^{n+1} a_i \geq (k+1)(k+2)/2$ and $a_{n+1} \geq a_n$. Show that there is a special $k+1$ coloring on $a_1, \ldots, a_{n+1}$.

Note that special k coloring implies there are at least 1 distinct labels of color 1, 2 distinct labels of color 2, $\ldots$, k distinct labels  of color k, for some ordering of the k colors.

PS: my previous version required that each color group contain at most one ball of any given label i. But that makes the claim false as pointed out by Fedor.

Comment: you probably also mean that $a_{n+1}\leqslant k+1$, otherwise the claim does not hold

Comment: @FedorPetrov sorry you are absolutely right the original statement was false. I made a correction by removing the condition that each color can contain only one ball of a given label i. Instead I stipulate on the number of distinct labels under each color.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This follows directly from the following

**Theorem.** Assume that $n\geqslant k>0$ are integers; $0\leqslant a_1\leqslant a_2\leqslant \ldots \leqslant a_n$ are non-negative integers; we have $a_i$ balls with label $i$, and want to color them in $k$ colors *nicely*, that is, different colors have different number of distinct labels, and each color being used for at least one ball. This is possible if and only if the following *condition N*: $$a_1+\ldots+a_{n-j}\geqslant (k-j)(k-j+1)/2\tag{$\star$}$$ for all $j=0,1,\ldots,k-1$, holds.

**Proof.**

1. If a nice coloring exists, Condition N holds.

Indeed, let the color $i$ have $b_i$ distinct labels so that $0<b_1<b_2<\ldots<b_k$. Look at the following $k-j$ colors:
$j+1,\ldots,k$. They have in total not less than $(j+1)+\ldots+k$ labels. This includes at most $j(k-j)$ labels belonging to the set of labels $\{n-j+1,\ldots,n\}$. Therefore at least $((j+1)+\ldots+k)-j(k-j)=1+\ldots+(k-j)=(k-j)(k-j+1)/2$ labels must be realized by at most $a_1+\ldots+a_{n-j}$ balls with labels at most $n-j$.

2. If condition N holds, a nice coloring exists. Note that Condition N may be reformulated in the terms which do not appeal to the ordering of $a_i$'s: for each $j=1,2,\ldots, k$ for any $n-j$ labels there exist at least $(k-j)(k-j+1)/2$ balls of these labels.

The claim clearly holds for $k=1$. So, using induction we may assume that $k>1$ and it holds for $k-1$. $(\star)$ for $j=k-1$ yields $a_1+\ldots+a_{n-(k-1)}\geqslant 1$, equivalently, $a_{n-k+1}>0$. Call labels $n-k+1,\ldots,n$ joyful. We may take one ball with each joyful label and color them all in color $k$. If we verify that the remaining balls satisfy Condition N for $k-1$ colors, we may color *some* of them in colors $1,2,\ldots,k-1$ so that there exist *exactly* $i$ distinct labels for the $i$-th color for $i=1,2,\ldots,k-1$. Coloring all other balls in color $k$ we get a nice coloring.

For verifying Condition N for the new collection of balls and $k-1$ colors,  we should prove that for each $j=1,2,\ldots, k-2$ for any $n-j$ chosen labels there exist at least $(k-1-j)(k-j)/2$ balls of these chosen labels. Let there be $n-k-i$ not joyful chosen labels and $k+i-j$ joyful chosen labels, here $i$ is between $0$ and $\min(j,n-k)$. There exist at least $a_1+\ldots+a_{n-k-i}$ balls of not joyful chosen labels and at least $(a_{n-k+1}-1)+\ldots+(a_{n-k+(k+i-j)}-1)=a_{n-k+1}+\ldots+a_{n+i-j}-(k+i-j)$ balls of joyful chosen labels.
Between $k+2i-j$ numbers $a_{n-k-i+1},\ldots,a_{n+i-j}$ the $k+i-j$ numbers
$a_{n-k+1},\ldots,a_{n+i-j}$ are the largest. Thus
$$
a_{n-k+1}+\ldots+a_{n+i-j}\geqslant \frac{k+i-j}{k+2i-j}(a_{n-k-i+1}+\ldots+a_{n+i-j}).
$$
Also, obviously,
$$
a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n-k-i}\geqslant \frac{k+i-j}{k+2i-j}(a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n-k-i}).
$$
Summing up and using $(\star)$ for $j-i$ at place of $j$ we get
$$
(a_{1}+\ldots+a_{n-k-i})+(a_{n-k+1}+\ldots+a_{n+i-j})
\geqslant \frac{k+i-j}{k+2i-j}(a_1+\ldots+a_{n+i-j})\\
\geqslant \frac{k+i-j}{k+2i-j}\cdot \frac{(k-j+i)(k-j+i+1)}2=:A
$$
It suffices to prove that $A\geqslant (k+i-j)+(k-j)(k-j-1)/2$. Well,
$$2A-2(k+i-j)-(k-j)(k-j-1)=\frac{i(k+i-j-1)(k+2i-j-1)}{k+2i-j}.$$
Since $j\leqslant k-1$, this is non-negative.

Comment: Thanks a lot maestro Fedor! Your insight on using the last k partial sums is indeed key and helped me formulate my own proof keeping the sorted nature of a_i: instead of taking the last k colors as joyful, I take the greedily latest k colors that preserve the ordering.